# When to write on my db

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

I have an android Activity which uses SQLite and in the Activity the user can make changes that affect the data stored in the DB.

I was wondering what's better: writing a change in the DB in the moment it's made, or saving all those changes in a sort of List and write everything in the DB on the OnStop method (at the end of the Activity).

Comment: Do it immediately on change. If you want use a save button and save data when user clicks on it

Comment: My mantra on database usage: `open it, use it, close it. open it, use it, close it. open it, use it, close it. ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write changes as they happen. Unless you have a VERY heavy dataflow which requires such micro-optimizations, you are simply adding to complexity of your solution by delaying the write.